# Next and Previous button for looping scrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview

I have a UIScroll view that scrolls between 4 different XIBs. I would like to disable the ability of scrolling by touching the scroll view. There are two buttons at the bottom of my app that I would like to scroll forward and back in a loop. The ViewController is forced to be in landscape orientation, and the scroll view dimensions are 568w x 217h.

Here is an image of the layout: [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNxc6.png)

Answer (score 0):

What you are tying to do is called "paging", and in my opinion a scroll view in not the best way to do so... here is a great project that looks like what you need:

https://github.com/caesarcat/InfinitePagingView

Hope this helps